# How can I give parameter values while executing a jar?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I'm having two input parameters in my main class such as:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException, ParseException {

    DataFromES df = new DataFromES();
    String year = "";
    String[] month = {""};

    for (String m : month) {
        df.receiveData(year,m);

    }

    System.out.println("Excel Generated");
}
```

I've already generated the `jar` for my project. But 'm quite unsure of how to pass values to the `jar` while executing it through `CMD`. I'm already aware of how to pass parameters to the jar, but then unclear how can I pass values to the above two `Strings`.

Comment: `year = args[0];` ?

Comment: Parameters from command line are stored in the args Array in main class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid reinventing the wheel and bugs, you should consider using a library like [**Apache Commons CLI**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) which will parse your command properly for you.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption(
        Option.builder("y")
            .required(true)
            .hasArg(true)
            .desc("The year")
            .longOpt("year")
            .build()
    );
    options.addOption(
        Option.builder("m")
            .required(true)
            .desc("The months")
            .numberOfArgs(Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES)
            .longOpt("month")
            .build()
    );
    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    CommandLine cmd;
    try {
        cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.err.println( "Could not parse the command due to: " + e.getMessage());
        HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        formatter.printHelp( "java", options );
        return;
    }
    String year = cmd.getOptionValue("y");
    String[] months = cmd.getOptionValues("m");
    // Rest of your code here
}
```

You will then be able to provide your arguments using `-y` or `--year` in case of the year and using `-m` or `--month` in case of the months. The usage will also be printed in case of a parsing error.

---

If you want to do it manually (assuming that you have the year first followed by the months), your code will then be:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 2)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not enough arguments");
    String year = args[0];
    String[] months = new String[args.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(args, 1, months, 0, months.length);
    ...
}
```

But we should add more tests to ensure that the total amount of arguments is correct and the arguments are valid which is the reason why I propose to use a library instead.

Comment: Explanation was spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Inside you main() method, you need to declare your 2 variables :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String year = args[0];
    String month = args[1];

    .... your treatment ...
}
```

And so, pass year as the first argument and month as the second ;)

Comment: made the second param as : String[] month = args[1].split(",") and it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java` command to pass parameters to args,like this:

```
java -cp jar-name.jar complete-class-name "2016" "08"
```

And your code like this:

```
String year = args[0];
String month = args[1];
```